# Доступ к сетевой папке из php

Tags: php, windows, apache

Нужно получить файлы из сетевой папки через php (web-сервер Apache+php на Windows2008 R2 Enterprise)
На самом сервере я могу подключить сетевую папку, все данные мне в ней доступны, но когда пытаюсь тоже самое сделать через php, в ответ получаю 
false.
Пробовала подключаться следующим образом:

```php
$directory_path="\\\\\192.168.1.5\\my_dir\\";
//$directory_path="//192.168.1.5\my_dir\";
if(!is_dir($directory_path))
  die($directory_path.' is not direction!');
if(!file_exists($directory_path.'text.txt'))
  die($directory_path.'text.txt not found!');
```

Программа валится еще на проверке директории. Пробовала прописывать разные пути. На сам каталог дала пользователям полные права, Apache запускаю под администратором, в реестре пробовала прописывать переменную HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\RestrictNullSessAccess = 0 по совету [отсюда](http://www.falsecode.ru/blog/?p=245).
 Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие еще настройки нужно сделать, чтобы эта сетевая папка стала доступной?
 P.S. Попробовала создать ссылку по [рекомендации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847164/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-windows-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php).

```bsh
 mklink /D MySymLink "\\server\path\to\folder"
```

PHP видит каталог MySymLink  но на все что внутри него выводит false.

Answer (score 1):

У вас лишний слеш
попробуйте вот так:

```
$directory_path="\\\\192.168.1.5\\my_dir\\";
```

Или вот так

```
$path = '\\networkdrive\somepath\your_directory';

$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$drive_letter = "Q";

system("net use ".$drive_letter.": \"".$path."\" ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:no>nul 2>&1");
$location = $drive_letter.":/somepath/your_directory";

if ($handle = opendir($location)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    echo "$entry";
    } 
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Пробовала, не работает(

Comment: Подключение папки через php тоже не сработало (пробовала командой exec).  Мне подсказали, что скорее всего придется смотреть в сторону FTP ((

Answer (score 0):

Доработал пример предложенный **becouse**.

```
//Нужно экранировать каждый слэш:
$path = '\\\\networkdrive\\somepath\\your_directory';

//Здесь servername - имя удалённого сервера или общедоступное имя NAS
$user = "servername\username";

$pass = "password";

// Буква диска не работает с NAS-ом или не всегда работает,
// поэтому подключаемся без неё,
// а при дальнейшем обращении к файлам используем 
// "\\\\networkdrive\\somepath\\your_directory\\your_files"
//$drive_letter = "Q";

//Оба варианта рабочие
//exec("net use ".$path." ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:yes>nul 2>&1");
system("net use ".$path." ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:yes>nul 2>&1");


if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    echo "$entry";
    } 
    closedir($handle);
}
```